# Angularjs filtering over array of objects in ngRepeat doesn't restore items with empty search property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Please, consider the following example:

Template:

```
<body  ng-controller="MainCtrl">
Search: <input ng-model="search.$" ><br>
Search by tag: <input ng-model="search.tag" >
    <p ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search">
        <span>{{item.content}}</span> <span>{{item.tag}}</span>
    </p>
</body>
```

Script:

```
 app.controller('MainCtrl',  function ($scope, $filter, filterFilter) {
 $scope.items = [
     {content:'3333113', tag:['a','b','c']},
     {content:'111111g', tag:['b','c','d']},
     {content:'345345', tag:[]},
     {content:'2221122', tag:['c','d','e']},
     {content:'2221122', tag:[]},
     {content:'333', tag:[]}
  ];
});
```

When searching via the first input `ng-model="search.$"` with any data everything is Ok.
When searching via the seond input `ng-model="search.tag"` search does work by tags like `a`, `b`, but when it is cleared the restored array lacks the items which had empty search value, e.g. `{content:'2221122', tag:[]}` in this example.

[jsBin example](http://jsbin.com/EbojOZA/7/edit?html,js,output)

Why does it happen ? Is there an easy way to avoid it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer:

here is a working code: http://jsbin.com/AwunOyAt/2

You need a directive to make `search.tag` undefined when it's empty:

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('modelUndefined', function(){
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope,elm,attrs,ngModel){
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(val){             
         return val === "" ? undefined : val;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

**html:**

```
<input ng-model="search.tag" model-undefined>
```

---

#### Long answer:

From the docs of [filter:filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter:filter):

> #### In HTML Template Binding
>
> {{ filter_expression | filter:expression:comparator }}
>
> **Parameters#expression**
>
> Object: A pattern object can be used to filter specific properties on objects contained by array. For example {name:"M", phone:"1"} predicate will return an array of items which have property name containing "M" and property phone containing "1". A special property name $ can be used (as in {$:"text"}) to accept a match against any property of the object. That's equivalent to the simple substring match with a string as described above.

As you can see, the filter expression can be **an object with more then one predicates**.

#### how to trace it?

Initially `ngModel` won't set `search.tag` until there is an input so it's still undefined.

First I pass an input into `search.$`, the search object looks like so:

```
$scope.search = {
  '$' : 'something'
}
```

Then I'll pass something into `search.tag`, the search object:

```
$scope.search = {
  '$' : 'something',
  'tag': 'anything'
}
```

But when I clear it then the search object still have the `tag` property

```
$scope.search = {
  '$' : 'something',
  'tag': ''
}
```

`filter:filter` filters based on both predicates, this is the [source code](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.11/src/ng/filter/filter.js):

```
  case "object":
    // jshint +W086
    for (var key in expression) {
      (function(path) {
        if (typeof expression[path] == 'undefined') return;
        predicates.push(function(value) {
          return search(path == '$' ? value : (value && value[path]), expression[path]);
        });
      })(key);
```

- In our case the expression is the `search object` , and the paths are `$` and `tag`.
- See this line: `if (typeof expression[path] == 'undefined') return;`
- If we set `search.tag = undefined` , the filter ignores it.
- But If we set `search.tag = ''`  this `tag` path is added to the predicates check array.

#### How to enforce `ngModel` to make `search.tag` undefined when it's empty?

See the directive above, you need to use `ngModelController#$parsers` to change the way the view value is converted when it updates the model.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you please elaborate on `$parsers` use in the `Long answer`. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @IgorMalyk It's a little hard to explain, but I hope it's clear now.

Comment: So basically after first edit it will search by `''` instead of by `undefined` as a predicate and those items are filtered away and stay like that. If the arrays had at least `''` instead of being empty it would work as well. Thanks a lot, great answer !

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it helps but I put in the following:

```
<p>{{search.tag == undefined}}</p>
```

It then showed that initially it is `undefined` und later on it is an empty string (if you empty the input). The search results then kind of make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is a change in AngularJS version 1.2.10. Using https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.2/angular.min.js does not eliminate empty entries.